# nservicebus critical error Exception code: 0x80131623

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm getting the following error on starting up NServicebus.Host.exe

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x9124e4c7, on thread 0x2094. The error code is 0x80131623.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

I get this when I start the project through Visual Studio or directly through a command prompt and am having a hard time troubleshooting why it's crashing - suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a failfast.  Resembles [this issue](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1137).

Comment: Did you try this on another machine? What version of NServiceBus are you running? What version of VisualStiudio?

Comment: What output is written to the nsb log file (probably same directory as the exe)?

Comment: thanks @HansPassant - your comment took me in the correct direction and I started looking at the event log - found a better answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @hanspassant, I was able to track down the issue:

My ServiceControl queue did not exist, once created the problem went away.

This was the error that ended up in the Windows Application Log:

> Service cannot be started. System.ArgumentException: Queue must be
>   transactional if you configure your endpoint to be transactional
>   (Particular.ServiceControl@HFORTE-2).    at
>   NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Init(Address address,
>   TransactionSettings settings, Func`2 tryProcessMessage, Action`2

The problem ended up being servicecontrol related. I think Particular fixed the bug inside the NServicebus, as per this link [FatalExecutionEngineError FailFast](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1137)
but not in the ServiceControl plugin.